# How to define a range with a variable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

From the active cell that I get the rank, I want to select the cells of this row of column H to V, then copy the same line to the end of the sheet, whatever the end of the sheet.

```
function deBugEssaiMaj() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var laPremiereLigne = sh.getActiveCell().getRow(); 

  var source = sh.getRange("G"&laPremiereLigne&":V"&laPremiereLigne);

};
```

I have an error:

> range not found

Comment: Hi David, welcome to SO! Can you please format your code? Take a look at the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: Please tell what application or library you are using. Is this google-spreadsheets using google-apps-script? Please clarify in your tags, otherwise people here will not find your question.

Comment: I would advise you, to use a better code style. Especially adding spaces around operators like "&" makes the mistake easier to detect for others.

Answer (score 3):

What is definitely wrong is the `&`-operator. It is not used for concatenation of strings in JavaScript. You have to use `+`

```
 var source = sh.getRange("G" + laPremiereLigne + ":V" + laPremiereLigne);
```

With `&` it is also valid JavaScript, but does not make any sense. It is used for bitwise and operation, which is not defined for strings. So the strings are converted to numbers resulting in `NaN`. `NaN` bitwise anded with anything yields `0`, so you basically called `getRange(0)`